# what is wrong with this query?(sql convert date)

Tags: mysql, sql

The following query is working perfectly :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MsUser 
WHERE absensi_tanggal = DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( "' .$query_array['datepicker'] . '", \'%m/%d/%Y\' ) , \'%Y-%m-%d\' )
```

However, this query is not working. I should miss something there :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MsUser 
WHERE absensi_tanggal BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( "' .$query_array['datepicker1'] . '", \'%m/%d/%Y\' ) , \'%Y-%m-%d\' ) 
AND DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( "' .$query_array['datepicker2'] . '", \'%m/%d/%Y\' ) , \'%Y-%m-%d\' )
```

The query above always return 0 result.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks :D

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Post the error you are getting back, it will help to troubleshoot your issue. Also retag the question to know wich RDBM's are you using.

Comment: Done, please see my updated question. Sorry :D

Comment: Are you sure you have data within range you are selecting? Try to print actual query (after gluing all strings together).

Comment: add some debug that wriutes the values of DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( "' .$query_array['datepicker1'] . '", \'%m/%d/%Y\' ) , \'%Y-%m-%d\' ) 
AND DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( "' .$query_array['datepicker2'] . '", \'%m/%d/%Y\' ) to a log file.  Are they correct?

Comment: Keep in mind some databases are > < for between and others are >= <=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `STR_TO_DATE` returns a proper DATE type value that can be used with BETWEEN, have you tried simply:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MsUser 
WHERE absensi_tanggal 
BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE( "' .$query_array['datepicker1'] . '", \'%m/%d/%Y\' )
AND 
STR_TO_DATE( "' .$query_array['datepicker2'] . '", \'%m/%d/%Y\' )
```

My guess would be that MySQL is choking on converting front a string to a date and then back to a string and then back again to a date to make the `BETWEEN` work.

Also, try this to make it a bit tidier:

```
"
SELECT * 
FROM MsUser 
WHERE absensi_tanggal 
BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('{$query_array['datepicker1']}','%m/%d/%Y')
AND 
STR_TO_DATE('{$query_array['datepicker2']}','%m/%d/%Y');
"
```

And just in case you aren't confirming that the value of `datepicker1` is earlier than `datepicker2`, you can run the query like this to be sure (though I advise only for testing):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MsUser 
WHERE 
(
absensi_tanggal 
BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('{$query_array['datepicker1']}','%m/%d/%Y')
AND 
STR_TO_DATE('{$query_array['datepicker2']}','%m/%d/%Y')
) OR (
absensi_tanggal 
BETWEEN 
STR_TO_DATE('{$query_array['datepicker2']}','%m/%d/%Y')
AND 
STR_TO_DATE('{$query_array['datepicker1']}','%m/%d/%Y')
);
"
```